# How to create a angular library with external js library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-cli

I have an angular cli project, which aims to be a feature library and used in another project. In my library project, I used some javascript library (no typescript file in it) in the component typescript file as following:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
this.leafletMap = L.map('mapid');
```

My feature library project itself works fine when running `ng serve`. However, if I publish my library and install it in the testing project, the console will complain

> ERROR ReferenceError: L is not defined.

Can anyone help me to solve this issues?

Comment: can you provide your build (dist) output of you angular library

Comment: it works now, but I need to manually remove the automatically generated import of "leaflet/index" to "leaflet" in the disk folder~